# RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField received naive datetime while time zone support is active

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

```
pst = pytz.timezone('US/Pacific')
start_time = pst.localize(datetime.strptime(data_post['startTime'], fmt))
if 'endTime' in data_post:
   end_time = pst.localize(datetime.strptime(data_post['endTime'], fmt))
```

I got the below Warning

> /venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py:1393:
>   RuntimeWarning: DateTimeField DashboardTestResult.start_time received
>   a naive datetime (2019-09-27 00:00:00) while time zone support is
>   active.   RuntimeWarning)